# Python object is in list yet isn't?

Tags: python

I am having an issue trying to make a small text-fantasy type game involving classes for each type of entity (a wall, the player, a book etc). I have a class called room that looks like this:

```
class Room:

    def __init__(self, desc, items, wallF, wallB, wallL, wallR, isdark):
        self.desc = desc
        self.items = items
        self.wallF = wallF
        self.wallB = wallB
        self.wallL = wallL
        self.wallR = wallR
        self.isdark = False
```

now I have two rooms that are defined like this (not saying that its right):

```
roomstart = Room('There is a hole in the ceiling where you seemed to have fallen through, there is no way back up...', [candle], True, False, False, False, False)
room2 = Room('You enter a small cobblestone cavort. It is dark, and the smell of rot pervades you', [spellbook], False, True, False, True, True)
```

now, the problem is this: when I run the program it works fine up until I try to take the candle from `roomstart`, it then spits out the error that the candle is not in a list:

```
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError("'candle' is not in list",), <traceb
ack object at 0x00B8D648>)
```

(yes, I did use `sys.exc_info()`)

each object, (the candle, a dagger, a robe etc) has a class as well:

```
class Object:

    def __init__(self, desc, worth, emitslight, readable, wearable, name):
        self.desc = desc
        self.worth = worth
        self.emitslight = emitslight
        self.readable = readable
        self.wearable = wearable
        self.name = name
```

here is the code for user input:

```
def handleinput():
global moves
room = Player.location
if room.isdark == True:
    print 'It is rather dark in here...'
else:
    print room.desc, 'You see here:',
    for i in room.items:
        print i.name
input = str(raw_input('What now? ')).lower()
if 'look' in input:
    if room.isdark==True:
        print "You can't see anything! Its too dark."
    else:
        print 'You see:',room.desc, room.items.name
        if room.wallF == True:
            print 'There is an exit to the front.'
        elif room.wallB == True:
            print 'There is an exit behind you.'
        elif room.wallL == True:
            print 'There is an exit to your left.'
        elif room.wallR == True:
            print 'There is an exit to your right.'

elif 'grab' in input:
    if room.isdark==True:
        print 'You flail about blindly in the dark room!'
    else:
        input2 = str(raw_input('Take what? '))
        try:
            popp = room.items.index(input2)
            print popp
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()
            print input2.title(),"doesn't exist!"
        else:
            print "You take the",input2,"and store it in your knapsack."
            room.items.pop(popp)
            Player.inventory.append(input2)

elif 'wipe face' in input:
    os.system('cls')
moves += 1
```

Comment: Well, at least we can't complain that he *didn't* show what he's tried so far.

Comment: you know `candle` and `'candle'` are different objects, right?

Comment: It's great that you show us the code, really, it helps. What would help even more is for you to try to find the *minimal* piece of code that demonstrates your problem. That would help SO help you.

Comment: @gnibbler if you're talking about 'candle' at the end of the candle object construction yes, 'candle' is the object.name string that I'm using to actually name the candle for ingame tagging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object `candle` is in the list, but the string `'candle'` is not.  You may wish to solve this with a dictionary of the objects:

```
objects = {}
objects['candle'] = candle
objects['robe'] = robe
...
```

Then, you can find the index of the item via

```
popp = room.items.index(objects[input2])
```

Comment: Wow! That worked perfectly! Just gotta remember to add the objects to the list ;) again thanks very much! The sweet message of success: `There is a hole in the ceiling where you seemed to have fallen through, there is
 no way back up... You see here: candle
What now? take
Take what? candle
You take the candle and store it in your knapsack.
There is a hole in the ceiling where you seemed to have fallen through, there is
 no way back up... You see here: What now?`